# Magento 2: Spinner kept running and not showing data after creating custom admin grid

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, ui-grid

I checked a few answers before asking this question, I am new in Magento2 and learning from udemy course, I am sharing screenshot as well as my code:

affiliate_member_listing.xml
path:magento/app/code/SimpleMagento/CustomAdmin/view/adminhtml/ui_component/affiliate_member_listing.xml

I read that it can be an issue because of dataSource, so I am sharing it first, so you don't need to dig into the whole code.

```
<dataSource name="affiliate_member_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">

        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">AffiliateGridDataProvider</argument>

        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">affiliate_member_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_end</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_end</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
```

Here is the full code of `affiliate_member_listing.xml`

```
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
   <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
     <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">affiliate_member_listing.affiliate_member_listing_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">affiliate_member_listing.affiliate_member_listing_data_source</item>
     </item>


    <item name="spinner" xsi:type="string">affiliate_member_columns</item>

    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array" >
        <item name="add" xsi:type="array" >
            <item name="name" xsi:type="string">add</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string">add a new member</item>
            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">primary</item>
            <item name="url" xsi:type="string">*/*/newAccount</item>
        </item>
    </item>
</argument>

<dataSource name="affiliate_member_listing_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">

        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">AffiliateGridDataProvider</argument>

        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">affiliate_member_listing_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">entity_end</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/provider</item>
                <item name="update_url" xsi:type="url" path="mui/index/render"/>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_end</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
</dataSource>

<container name="listing_top">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            <item name="stickyTmpl" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/sticky/toolbar</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <bookmark name="bookmarks">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">affiliate_member_listing</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </bookmark>
    <component name="columns_controls">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="columnsData" xsi:type="array">
                     <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">affiliate_member_listing.affiliate_member_listing.affiliate_member_columns</item>
                 </item>
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/columns</item>
                <item name="displayArea" xsi:type="string">dataGridAction</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </component>
    <filterSearch name="fulltext">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">affiliate_member_listing.affiliate_member_listing_data_source</item>
                <item name="chipsProvider" xsi:type="string">affiliate_member_listing.affiliate_member_listing.listing_top</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">affiliate_member_listing.affiliate_member_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.search</item>
                </item>

            </item>
        </argument>
    </filterSearch>
    <filters name="listing_filters">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="columnsProvider" xsi:type="string">affiliate_member_listing.affiliate_member_listing_data_source</item>
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">affiliate_member_listing.affiliate_member_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.filters</item>
                </item>
                <item name="templates" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filters" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select</item>
                            <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">affiliate_member_listing.affiliate_member_listing_data_source</item>
                    <item name="imports" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="visible" xsi:type="string">affiliate_member_listing.affiliate_member_listing.affiliate_member_columns.${ $.index }</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
            <item name="observers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="column" xsi:type="string">column</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </filters>

    <massaction name="listing_massaction">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="select" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">affiliate_member_listing.affiliate_member_listing.affiliate_member_columns.ids</item>
                <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_end</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <action name="delete">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">delete</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete</item>
                    <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="affiliate/member/massDelete"/>
                    <item name="confirm" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Delete items</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure?</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
        <action name="edit">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="type" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Edit</item>
                    <item name="callback" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string" >affiliate_member_listing.affiliate_member_listing.affiliate_member_columns</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string" >editSelected</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </action>
    </massaction>
    <paging name="listing_paging">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string" >affiliate_member_listing.affiliate_member_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string" >current.paging</item>
                </item>
                <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string" >affiliate_member_listing.affiliate_member_listing.affiliate_member_columns</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </paging>

    <columns name="affiliate_member_columns">

        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="provider" xsi:type="string" >affiliate_member_listing.affiliate_member_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string" >current</item>
                </item>
                <item name="editorConfig" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="selectProvider" xsi:type="string">edit</item>
                    <item name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_end</item>
                    <item name="clientConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="saveUrl" path="affiliate/member/inlineEdit" xsi:type="url" />
                        <item name="validateBeforeSave" xsi:type="boolean" >false</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
                <item name="childDefaults" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="fieldAction" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string" >affiliate_member_listing.affiliate_member_listing.listing_top.bookmarks</item>
                        <item name="target" xsi:type="string" >startEdit</item>
                        <item name="params" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="string" >${ $.data.rowIndex }</item>
                            <item name="1" xsi:type="boolean" >true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">affiliate_member_listing.affiliate_member_listing.affiliate_member_columns</item>
                        <item name="root" xsi:type="string">columns.${ $.index }</item>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">current.${ $.storageConfig.root}</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>

        <selectionsColumn name="ids">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="indexField" xsi:type="string">entity_end</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </selectionsColumn>

        <column name="entity_end">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">textRange</item>
                    <item name="sorting" xsi:type="string">asc</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">ID</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="name">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Name</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="address">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Address</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">30</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="created_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Created</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="updated_at" class="Magento\Ui\Component\Listing\Columns\Date">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">dateRange</item>
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/columns/date</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">date</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Updated</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">50</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>

        <column name="phone_number">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="editor" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="editorType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                        <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string">Phone Number</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </column>
     </columns>
  </container>
</listing>
```

file:`affiliate_member_index.xml`

> path:
>
> > magento/app/code/SimpleMagento/CustomAdmin/view/adminhtml/layout/affiliate_member_index.xml

```
 <body>
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <uiComponent name="affiliate_member_listing"/>
    </referenceContainer>
 </body>
```

di.xml

> path:
>
> > magento/app/code/SimpleMagento/CustomAdmin/etc/di.xml

```
<virtualType name="AffiliateGridDataProvider" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collection" xsi:type="object" shared="false">SimpleMagento\Database\Model\ResourceModel\AffiliateMember\Collection</argument>
        <argument name="filterPool" xsi:type="object" shared="false">MemberGridFilterPool</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

<virtualType name="MemberGridFilterPool" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\DataProvider\FilterPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\RegularFilter</item>
            <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\FullText</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>

<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\CollectionFactory">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="collections" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="affiliate_member_listing_data_source" xsi:type="string">SimpleMagento\Database\Model\Resource\Grid\Collection</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>

<virtualType name="SimpleMagento\Database\Model\Resource\Grid\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="string">affiliate_member</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">SimpleMagento\Database\Model\ResourceModel\AffiliateMember</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

file:`AffiliateMember.php`

> path:
>
> > magento/app/code/SimpleMagento/Database/Model/ResourceModel/AffiliateMember.php

```
  namespace SimpleMagento\Database\Model\ResourceModel;

  use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb;

  class AffiliateMember extends AbstractDb
  {
      protected function _construct()
     {
       $this->_init('affiliate_member','entity_end');
     }
  }
```

file:`Collection.php`

> path:
>
> > magento/app/code/SimpleMagento/Database/Model/ResourceModel/AffiliateMember/Collection.php

```
namespace SimpleMagento\Database\Model\ResourceModel\AffiliateMember;


use Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection;
use SimpleMagento\Database\Model\AffiliateMember;
use SimpleMagento\Database\Model\ResourceModel\AffiliateMember as 
AffiliateMemberResource;

class Collection extends AbstractCollection
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
      $this->_init(AffiliateMember::class, AffiliateMemberResource::class);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if someone needed anything else

Comment: can you please share the screen shot of the loading screen

Comment: I already shared screenshot in my question, anywhere here is the link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VlYWQzOfR4yHOB1_4-bQLxWPgme3N6bK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You can check your **var/log/exception.log** file. If you're getting any exceptions there ?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya No there is only connector, debug & system

Comment: Okay can you please remove your system.log file once and refresh your grid page and then check if system.log generated again then please open that file and check is there any critical issues there ?

Comment: @KishanSavaliya I don't found any issues in system.log after regenerate, here is screenshot of it:https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m7apH5BoJwasfMV679FpBRCCGZn8gLE2/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you please share your resource model code here

Comment: And please check in network if ajax call give any error response

Comment: @RutveeSojitra, There is no error of ajax or any in-network, I updated the question with resourceModel